# How can I use multiple ReactActivity with seperate js bundle?

Tags: react-native

How can I jump from one ReactActivity to another, each with a seperate js bundle?
MainActivty -> index.android.js
SettingActivity -> setting.android.js

I have read many Android examples using React-Native. Unfortunately, all of them are single activity.

Comment: May I know why do you want to do that?

Comment: My app has many activities with different functions. These functions are independent and may be developed by different people. So I want to use separate ReactActivity with its own js for each function. Development could be parallel and function upgrading could be separated.

Comment: Ok. I doubt this functionality is supported. One thing you can do is create component for different screens and work parallel using react native with redux for state management. You may refer https://github.com/fbsamples/f8app app from facebook for more details.

Comment: hey any updates on this how can we use multiple bundle files in android ?

Answer (score 2):

You can implement multiple activities that extend `ReactActivity`, and override the `getMainComponentName` method to the name of a root level component that you wish to use, such as the component defined in your `setting.android.js`

Make sure to register your component in `AppRegistry`.

If you wish to launch another activity, I've found it's easiest to launch the activity using `Linking` (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking.html) to fire an intent for an app url, and add the app url intent-filter to the activity in `AndroidManifest.xml`.